# HttpWebRequest, WebClient, HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load Alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, webclient, html-agility-pack

I am trying to use HtmlAgilityPack.Load in a shared hosting environment to parse a webpage.
However I am getting a system.net.sockets.socketexception error on my production page as the web host blocks the connection.

I am also getting the same problem trying to use the Ebay Developer .Net Library

Are there any alternatives (apart from a different host or dedicated server)
I have also tried WebClient and HttpWebRequest.

HttpWebRequest Code

```
HttpWebRequest oReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
resp = (HttpWebResponse)oReq.GetResponse();
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
readStream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), encode);
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(readStream.ReadToEnd());
```

Error Message for HttpWebRequest

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't seem related to Html Agility Pack but to the way you open the connection and the way the host work. Sample code and exception stack trace could help.

Comment: I have updated with code and error message. Yes it is the way the connection is opened and the host have confirmed they block the request. I need to know if there is another way to request a webpage that the host wont block.

Comment: Well, if they don't want you to connect, what do could you do? Or is there something you need to put in your request? Like a user-agent string?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry if I have been vague, it is my web host blocking the outbound connection